# Zentyal internet load sharing. how to avoid it

Tags: 10.04

We have configured zentyal as our gateway. but the internet speed is shared equally among all the machines. even when no machine is downloading anything. what i mean by this is if i have 10 machines and a 10MBPS line, each machine is maximum getting 1MBPS download speed, even when other machines are down.

i came to this conclusion, by checking the download speeds by directly connecting to my ISP and connecting to my ISP through zentyal.

Answer (score 1):

By default does not share the load. we can distribute the load using traffic shaping. The problem in my case was my network was not good. i replaced it and everything works like charm